# Random http command by user _apt with 100% CPU usage

Tags: apt, cpu, process

A random process with the command `http` owned by the user `_apt` starts automatically and uses 100% CPU. What is it? And why does it keep starting? I have attached a screenshot of the `top` command displaying the culprit.

[image]

Here's the output of `pstree -s #PID` where #PID is the corresponding process ID of that process:

```
systemd───apt.systemd.dai───apt.systemd.dai───apt-get───http
```

Comment: I’d open `htop` (must be installed first) and display the processes as a tree. You can also issue `pstree -s 15919` (the number is the PID of the process in question). Please add the output of this command to your question.

Comment: Thanks, @Melebius. I killed the process and will add the output the next time it comes back, which shouldn't take much time.

Comment: @Melebius, There you go. I have added the output.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Related questions: [Why do both cron and systemd execute automatic upgrades?](https://askubuntu.com/q/997089/250300); [How to disable `apt-daily.service` on Ubuntu cloud VM image?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315502/54675) Was your system off for a longer period (weeks, months)? Is your internet connection stable and fast enough?

Comment: I'll see the links and update the results here. Also, fast.com says it's about `28 Mbps` and I am a software developer so the laptop is working one quarter of a day, every day.

Comment: So, will I have to run the script mentioned in this answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315517/249899) every time I see the culprit process running?